# Handling errors with RxJS and Angular async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Angular & RxJS to make some reactive apps. I've recently seen that using Reactive programmation in a good way doesn't involve ".subscribe" which is more like imperative programming (manually pull the data).

I'm now trying to use Async pipe in Angular with RxJS and its working well, retrieving data asynchronously.

But how can I catch errors in the same way that I was doing with ".subscribe" like :

```
    this.http.getUsers().subscribe(
(success) => console.log(success) // everything is good
(error) => console.log(error) // an error happened 
)
```

With the reactive mode, the code is more like

```
this.http.getUsers().pipe(

switchMap(value => console.log(value))

); // no clue to handle errors with using subscribe
```

Even if the second method is more reactive, I wish I could find a way to handle errors as same as ".subscribe".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Subject which you populate on an error.

```
errorObs = new Subject()

result = this.http.getUsers().pipe(
    switchMap(value => console.log(value); //must return an Observable),
    catchError(e => {
        this.errorObs.next(true)
        return throwError(e)
    })
);
```

Your template will be something like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="result | async"> 
    success data
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="errorObs | async">
     error data
</ng-container>
```